# What is ContainerCreating in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

When updating a Kubernetes RollingUpdate deployment, `kubectl get pods` shows some of the pods spend a few minutes in the `ContainerCreating` state before moving to `Running`.  Unfortunately, [the official documentation on pod states](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase) doesn't include this as a documented state.  Even the kubernetes codebase [has only two mentions of the term](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=containercreating&type=), and neither has any sort of explanatory comment.

I've been doing some adjustments to [the rolling update deployment configuration value](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-update-deployment) (`maxUnavailable` and `maxSurge`) and [the probe configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#configure-probes) (`initialDelaySeconds`), and I'm unsure if the container startup time that these values are affecting is part of `ContainerCreating` or another state.

Comment: Could you add the k8s version that is applicable?

Comment: Right now we're using kubernetes 1.6.4, but it'd be interesting to know if it changes in any recent versions.

Answer (score 2):

The `ContainerCreating` state is applicable when the number of containers equals or is smaller than 0.

**Comprehensive**

According to [the code snippet that is defined in the question](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/427dfd5ce1483ead29568bf7c05a98c4c0ad081c/pkg/kubelet/kubelet_pods.go#L1297) the `ContainerCreating` status seems to be the `default waiting state`. Only if the `hasInitContainers` is `true` the `defaultWaitingState` will become `PodInitializing`. This is also indicated by [the test that is mentioned as well in the question](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/427dfd5ce1483ead29568bf7c05a98c4c0ad081c/pkg/kubelet/kubelet_test.go#L1550). In case of `without-old-record`, `with-old-record` or `something else` the `ContainerState` will be `Reason: startWaitingReason,` i.e. `"ContainerCreating"`

hasInitContainers

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/427dfd5ce1483ead29568bf7c05a98c4c0ad081c/pkg/kubelet/kubelet_pods.go#L1256

> ```
>   apiPodStatus.ContainerStatuses = kl.convertToAPIContainerStatuses(
>       pod, podStatus,
>       pod.Status.ContainerStatuses,
>       pod.Spec.Containers,
>       len(pod.Spec.InitContainers) > 0,
>       false,
>   )
>   apiPodStatus.InitContainerStatuses = kl.convertToAPIContainerStatuses(
>       pod, podStatus,
>       pod.Status.InitContainerStatuses,
>       pod.Spec.InitContainers,
>       len(pod.Spec.InitContainers) > 0,
>       true,
> )
> ```

Comment: Thanks.  That's interesting, but it's still not clear to me if the `initialDelaySeconds` time falls under `ContainerCreating` or comes after it, and if it's not part of it, what types of things would be happening during it (so I can attempt to decrease the time they take).

Comment: from my understanding, initialDelaySeconds starts once the container hits a Running state.  I use this setting to delay my health checks from killing a Java application while it starts. The check is set to 120 seconds, and the container enters a Ready state exactly 120 seconds after it enters Running.  I have experienced slow pulls from the registry causing excessive ContainerCreating, and have not seen an impact on the timing of the health checks.  YMMV